# Where we retrofit call & db CRUD in android mvvm?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have this funcation in the viewModel which call api

```
 private fun getPOS() {
  viewModelScope.launch {
        pos.postValue(Resource.Loading())
           val posResponse = accountRepository.getPos() //uspend function call API 
           pos.postValue(handlePOSResponse(posResponse))
       
     }
}

this function handle the result 
 private  fun handlePOSResponse(posResponse: Response<POS>): Resource<POS> {
     posResponse.body()?.let {
        if(it.result?.code==SUCCESS_CODE){

           saveResultInDB(it) ->is the line here?
           return Resource.Success(it)
        }
     }
```

in the fragment, I observe the data in the db which should act as a cache
my question that is my code sperate right or some operation must go to repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you are using ViewModel to save data to DB and you are fetching data from DB in the fragment.
the best way is you have to write another method actually use livedata in ViewModel and observing data in the fragment, something like this

add to ViewModel

```
public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes(){
return db.getNotes();
}
```

add to fragment

```
noteViewModel = new ViewMOdelProvider(this,ViewProvider
                    .AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(NoteViewModel.class);

noteViewModel.getAllNotes.observe(this,new Observe<List<Note>>(){
   public void onChanged(List<Note> notes){
      adapter.submitlist(notes);
   }
 });
```